# Vim under Cmder, how do I run my own version instead of the msysgit's default?

Tags: vim, msysgit, conemu, cmder

I'm trying to **run my own version of VIM** under **Cmder** console with no luck, every time I'm using Cmder, the default VIM from msysgit runs instead of my VIM installation, I just want to run my own VIM instead of msysgit's vim, I need to override it.

I've tried setting env variables settings from cmder with these settings:

Settings>Startup>Enviroment:

```
set VIMRUNTIME=C:\Program Files\Vim\vim74\  
set VIM=C:\Program Files\Vim\vim74\  
set MYVIMRC=C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc
```

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that the msysgit `vim` is in the `PATH` before your custom `vim`. Modify the `PATH` so that your custom vim is first (or modify the `vim.bat` helpers to point at your `vim`).

Comment: I'm not using vim.bat, I'm using my vim path instead as env variable. I was thinking that the PATH from Cmder could be overriding mine, so...how do I make my vim path to run with more precedence?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Carpetsmoker. I understood your comment after checking some of the .bat files inside Cmder path, I configured the file /vendor/init.bat under "Enhanced path" and set the path to my VIM. Works fine now.